# При изменении параметра ipywidgets исчезает график

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

Пишу небольшой скрипт, который позволит определять положение максимумов функции. Максимумы определяю с помощью `scipy.signal.find_peaks`. В функции есть параметр *distance*, который определяет минимальное количество точек между максимумами. Хочу при его изменении перестраивать положение максимумов и видеть их значение. Для этой цели использую `ipywidgets`.
Когда значение переменной находится в диапазоне, где значение максимумов не меняется, то график отображается нормально. Но если я выхожу за этот диапазон, то график пропадает.
В чем может быть проблема?

```
%matplotlib notebook
from ipywidgets import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

x = np.linspace(1500, 1600, num=1000)
y = np.cos(4*np.pi*190*1000/x)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
line, = ax.plot(x, y)
peaks, _ = find_peaks(y, distance=10)
line1, = ax.plot(x[peaks], y[peaks], "x")


def update(d = widgets.IntText(10)):
     
    peaks_new, _ = find_peaks(y, distance=d)
    
    line.set_ydata(y)
    line1.set_ydata(y[peaks_new])
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    
    print(y[peaks_new])
    print(peaks_new)
    

interact(update);
```

[image: Нормально]
[image: Ненормально]

Comment: я пока вижу только, что вы, вероятно, неверно передаете параметр `d`.  Есть подозрение, что вместо `peaks_new, _ = find_peaks(y, distance=d)`, нужно `peaks_new, _ = find_peaks(y, distance=int(d.value))`, а вместо `interact(update)` -  `interact(update())`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. К сожалению, в таком случае ipywidgets вообще перестает работать (нет ползунка).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте убрать верхнюю строку, вот эту:

```
%matplotlib notebook
```

У меня в Google Colab без неё сразу нормально заработало. Но может понадобиться сбросить настройки среды исполнения, если вы этот код уже выполняли до этого.

Другое дело, что у вас график настолько ровный, что от изменения значения виджета ничего не меняется. А если добавить в график рандомности:

```
y = np.cos(4*np.pi*190*1000/x) + np.random.rand(1000)/10
```

То там сразу логика ломается, нужно код самого `update` переделывать, чтобы он нормально работал. Видимо, нужно с нуля каждый раз весь график перерисовывать, а не только часть.

А вообще удобнее использовать слайдер, а не поле ввода:

```
interact(update, d=widgets.IntSlider(min=1, max=30, step=1, value=10));
```